# Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Authy_Api' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, namespaces, composer-php

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Authy_Api' not found","file":"\/home\/vagrant\/Code\/curve\/app\/controllers\/UsersController.php","line":9}}
```

I added `"authy-php": "2.*"` to my composer.json file under `"laravel/framework": "4.2.*"`

In my controller I instantiate it like so:

```
private $authy;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->authy = new Authy_Api(Config::get('authy.authy'));
}
```

I ran `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` and neither of the two solved my problem.

I also tried to do the top 10 google search results none of which fixed the problem.

Why is it not recognizing the class from the package?

Comment: The directory authy is in `vendor/`

Answer (score 0):

You should use in your controller:

```
$this->authy = new \Authy\Authy_Api(Config::get('authy.authy'));
```

and not

```
$this->authy = new Authy_Api(Config::get('authy.authy'));
```

because `Authy_Api` is defined in `Authy` namespace

Answer (score 0):

From the github readme. For composer require:

```
"authy/php": "2.*"
```

and for using the class

```
$authy_api = new Authy\AuthyApi('#your_api_key');
```

**Reference**

[Authy/Php Readme](https://github.com/authy/authy-php#php-client-for-authy-api)